# How to select the node type when creating HDInsight clusters using azure cli?

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-cli

I am trying to create clusters on HDInsight using azure cli but I cannot find a way to select the node types when creating the cluster. The command I am using to create the cluster is something like this:

```
az group deployment create --name $deploymentName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --template-file $templateFilePath \
--parameters clusterName=$deploymentName \
             clusterLoginPassword=$loginPassword \
             location=$resourceGroupLocation \
             clusterWorkerNodeCount=$wNodes \
             clusterKind=$clusterKind \
             clusterVersion=$clusterVersion \
             containerName=$containerName \
             sshPassword=$loginPassword
```

The relevant part from template file is:

```
"computeProfile": {
                "roles": [
                    {
                        "name": "headnode",
                        "minInstanceCount": 1,
                        "targetInstanceCount": 2,
                        "hardwareProfile": {
                            "vmSize": "Large"
                        },
                        "osProfile": {
                            "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
                                "username": "[parameters('sshUserName')]",
                                "password": "[parameters('sshPassword')]"
                            }
                        },
                        "virtualNetworkProfile": null,
                        "scriptActions": []
                    },
```

Comment: Could you please share your template here?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT edited the question to have the relevant parts of the template.json

Answer (score 0):

When using the azure hdinsight cluster create command, you can set the size of the head, worker, and ZooKeeper nodes by using the **--headNodeSize**, **--workerNodeSize**, and **--zookeeperNodeSize** parameters.

**Note:** Azure CLI 2.0 does not support creating an HDInsight cluster.

You need to use Azure CLI 1.0 to create an HDInsight cluster.

For more details, refer "[Create HDInsight clusters using the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-create-linux-clusters-azure-cli)".